# Make rest https client with authentification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl

I am trying to communicate with a rest webservice. I have tested it with advanced rest client from google. The webservice works just fine. The problem is with my code:

```
String uri ="https://192.168.160.180:8443/RebateWebService/version";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpsURLConnection connection =(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//String encoded = Base64.encode("6:4711"); 
// String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic Njo0NzEx");
String lol;
if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    lol="erreur de connection";
} else {
    InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
    lol=xml.toString();
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Here is the exception that has been thrown:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cert's 'CN' field is a domain(e.g. stackoverflow.com),not a ip.

Comment: I am working with a local rest webservice I can not write a domaine name